# Confusion about C++ multiply operation

Tags: c++

The following is making me confused -

If you multiply `float` with 10 (`integer`) look what happened,
also these types of operation seems strange !

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x1 = 0.1;// x1 *10 = 1  ture
    float x2 = 0.7;//x2 *10 = 7 false answer give 0.6
    float x3 = 0.8;//x3 *10 = 8 true
    float x4 = 0.9;// x4 * 10 = 9 false ops! the answer is 8
    int f  = x4 * 10 ;
    cout<<f ;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Well, [ideone](http://ideone.com/P4cCX2) outputs `9`.

Comment: You are storing the returned value as an int not as a float.

Comment: you copy the same code ?

Comment: There must be a zillion duplicates out there - it has to do with floating point number representation and precision. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Simply put - `float` and `double` are binary and inexact. It's possible `0.9` is not representable directly in binary, so it's perhaps represented as `0.8999899898` (or something), hence the round down to 8

Comment: @Angew That link should be auto-posted every time a post mentions `float` or `double`:)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Same goes for Android and Crash which should shove "POST YOUR LOGCAT" right in their faces!

Comment: x2 ... 0.6? - don't you mean 6?

Comment: Angew you are right that's what i find

Comment: some real numbers can't be represented as float or double 
like .9 and 1.2 etc cos 0.9 equvilat to 0.8999999 
the alterantive for theses numbers is Decimal representaion

Comment: @AdriC.S. Just be lucky this time. You will get 8 from time to time. :P

Comment: @Angew: No, it shouldn't. It's verbose. Did you ever read it all? Instead: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Was that comment to me or to Joachim? Either way, I've read Goldberg's paper. Anyway, I linked to the first Google hit for "What every ...". I'll bookmark your link, I guess.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The article you cite doesn't begin to give you enough information to use floating point successfully.  You really do need all of the information in "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".  (And that article is the opposite of verbose.  If it suffers from any problem, it's that it is too succinct, which makes it more difficult to understand.)

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yeah. I just tried it once and forgot about it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

floats are always rounded down (13.999999 is 13 as an int). Floating point arithmetic is subject to minor rounding errors. Try this:

```
int f  = (x4 * 10) + 0.5;
```

It'll only work with positive numbers, but proves how to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to save the result into `int`, not `float`. This will cut the float part off, only keep the integer part, e.g. `(int) 6.999 = 6`.

If you do want to get the ***expected*** result, you should at least round it:

```
int f  = x4 * 10 + 0.5;
                 ^^^^^
                   | +0.5 here to round it
```

*Note:* as commented by @JamesKanze, as there are [*multiple definitions of rounding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking), `+0.5` *may* not work for negative numbers (use `-0.5` instead). To make your work easier, there is also a [`std:round()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) you can use since `C++11`).

Or save it as what it should be, i.e. `float`:

```
float f  = x4 * 10;
^^^^^
```

---

**P.S.:** To read on, check out [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: There's also a function `std::round` in C++11.  Adding `0.5` doesn't work for negative numbers, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're using int for the type of f, so accuracy is lost. Try with:

```
float f = x4 * 10.0;
```

and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Float numbers can not exactly represent numbers. For example consider expression **1 / 3**

You are assigning the result of the multiplication to an integral variable. in this case the float number is truncated because its fraction is thrown off.

Use instead

```
float f  = x4 * 10 ;
```

Comment: `Float numbers can not exactly represent numbers` There are many, many numbers that they can exactly represent just fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In fact, every floating point number (except the infinities and NaNs) does exactly represent a number.  The problem is just the reverse: not every number can be represented by a floating point number.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's what he said!

Comment: @Poldie No.  He said the opposite, that floating point numbers can not exactly represent numbers.  They do exactly represent numbers.  Maybe not the numbers you want, but floating point _representation_ is exact.  (Floating point arithmetic is also exact, in the sense that every operation has an exact result.  Not the same result as you'd get with arithmetic over the reals, however.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I did not say any such thing. Anyway I think it's clear when people talk about this that they are talking about exactness when compared with arithmetic over the reals. I don't see a great need to be pedantic about that.

Comment: @JamesKanze  That was a quotation from the answer he was commenting on.